# NoHostAvailableException in Cassandra though host is online

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am using a DataStax Cassandra client version 2.1.1 and I connect to 10 different clusters. I use one session per cluster and we are doing inserts to different clusters in our server.

We have prepared statements to insert queries per host and when we need to do an insert to the particular cluster, we get the session object's connection and do the insert.

When we ran load test, two things we noted:
1) I do an insert to one host(X) for a long time(burst of calls,etc) - no issues are found
2) Do a burst call to two clusters(X,Y) -then most of the records inserted into the first cluster(Y) fails

Any reason for this?

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: Are you really writing to 10 cassandra clusters? Do you mean nodes?

Comment: Hi pHact,  No, I am writing to 10 cassandra clusters - basically consider a situation where I do the paritioning(shrading) in the application side.

Comment: Hi pHact,  No, I am writing to 10 cassandra clusters - basically consider a situation where I do the paritioning(shrading) in the application side.

Comment: Hm so multiple cluster objects in one app? Java driver?

Comment: Datastax Cassandra 2.1.1.

Comment: That is your cassandra version

Comment: No,that is my casandra driver version. Maven dependency used : <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>   
  </dependency>

Comment: Okay. I'll try to replicate this and get back

Comment: A "NoHostAvailableException" could be yielded if you are getting driver side timeouts to hosts which marks them down and unavailable for queries until connection is re-established (typically within 1 second).  Do you see anything in your logs about "Defuncting connection" or "Timed out waiting for server response"?    Are you by chance doing batch inserts or possibly overwhelming your cassandra nodes?

Comment: Perhaps you could share the part of your code that sets up the connection too? It seems you have confirmed when asked above that you are writing to different clusters? A different cluster object is required for each cluster you write to. Perhaps though you mean datacenter and not cluster? Some output to show your clusters like `nodetool status` would help too

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue for the driver misbehaving. The actual problem was with the data model used. My data model had a map(Collection) datatype and during high load, there were timeouts. When I changed my datatype from Map to Text and when I added COMPACT STORAGE when I created tables, then things worked fine.

Yes, it is weird, but it worked. An explanation to why this works would really help.

Thanks,
Gopi